# Avoid to detect GESTURES in Android

Tags: android

i have problem with onTouch. I have GridLayout where i have 3x3 buttons like a image below.
[image]

B1,B2 -- is the Button view. My problem is, when i put 3 fingers on the screen at the same time and move all of them down then my phone detect it like threeSwipeGesture and make screenshot. How to avoid phone to detect gesture?

TIP: When i put 3 fingers one by one (tap 1 - wait second - tap 2 - wait second - tap 3) then i can move my fingers and gesture is not detected.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getActionMasked();
    int index = event.getActionIndex();
    int x = -1;
    int y = -1;

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            return false;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            gridLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#df4930"));
            set.clear();
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            x = (int) event.getX(index);
            y = (int) event.getY(index);

            for (int i = 0; i < gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View button = gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
                Rect outRect = new Rect(button.getLeft(), button.getTop(), button.getRight(), button.getBottom());
                if (outRect.contains(x, y)) {
                    set.add(button.getTag());
                }
            }
            if (set.size() == 4) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, set.toString());
                gridLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffc120"));
            }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here is error log in the console when gesture is detected.
`D/ViewRootImpl: cancle motionEvent because of threeGesture detecting`

Comment: which phone do you use? I have same issue before in xiaomi. i tried fix it and ask supporter of company. but there's no method. because system is top on any apps. if system process gesture, all app needs process cancel event.

Comment: I use Xiaomi too. If You want to use Your app to personal use You can disable Gestures in the settings. (I had "take screenshot" on 3 fingers swipe down gesture)
But i still need programictly solution becouse i cant required from any users of my app to disabling gestures on their phones ;/